# Carry values from an attribute on multiple elements to another attribute

Tags: javascript, attributes, getattribute

I have this JavaScript which detects whether the browser supports touch events, and then sets a touch event with every element that has a click event:

```
function isTouchEnabled() {
    if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick]');
        for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            all[i].setAttribute('ontouchstart', car);
            var car = all[i].getAttribute('onclick');
        }
    }
}
```

This works up until this bit: `all[i].setAttribute('ontouchstart', car);`

With this bit, I aimed to carry the attribute value from the click event to the touch event, but this does not work, because the touch event attribute value ends up being undefined. Can anybody solve this ?

Comment: The value you are setting has to be a string like `car()`

Comment: I don't quite understand

Comment: it's probably because the `car` variable is defined after the `all[i].setAttribute('ontouchstart', car);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function hitMe() {
    alert('I am hit !');
}
function isTouchEnabled() {
  if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('[onclick]');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      var car = all[i].getAttribute('onclick');
      all[i].setAttribute('ontouchstart', car);
    }
  }
}
isTouchEnabled();
```

```html
<div onclick="hitMe()">Click Me!</div>
```